# Granville Wood's Telegraph -- do we know the data rate and range?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I realize this is more a history of engineering question but I do not see a SE devoted to this so I thought I would ask here.

https://suiter.com/granville-woods-railway-telegraphy-patent-no-373383/ discusses a very interesting invention which allowed a moving train, long before radio, to get telegraphic messages but it does not provide details. I assume messages were stored and replayed at a much higher rate than an operator could key them.

But even so, I assume further that the amount of data would be very limited. For one thing, as the train moved beyond the station (and the range at which the messages could be transmitted is also of interest) I would guess that the ability to transmit dropped off very fast.

If anyone can provide more technical details on an invention I had only heard of recently, I would be very interested.

Perhaps this technology was superseded by radio or some other method of transmitting to moving trains that did not require proximity to the train station. Obviously continous communication with trains anywhere along the tracks would be incredibly valuable while transmitting a limited amount of data while a train passed a station assumes that there was no time to stop and simply physically pick up a bunch of paper telegrams. That is not to say that occasionally getting perhaps valuable messages without stopping -- emergencies like obstructed tracks could be signaled via lights along tracks -- would not be useful.

Comment: As usual, the text of the patent itself does not offer an easy answer to the question: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b3/ae/71/dbfe983a4a7134/US373383.pdf

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks, this is a good resource. It is clear from just a general knowledge of hardware that the storage had to be relatively slow mechanical device as seems to be indicated so the number of characters transmitted would be limited by how fast a paper tape could be read and tapped out. Also, dots and dashes had to be I wd think held for relatively long time and distinguishable -- u cd not have a microsecond dot and a two microsecond dash. So I have to wonder just how useful this system was, whether even a single message could reliably have been sent.